# Qt : restarting thread

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a GUI with Qt, I have a problem with playing with threads . I create a small GUi with two button stream and stopstream. my Problem is that I can't restart stream after stoping it:
below is a part of the code :

```
MainThread::MainThread(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent){

    bstream = new QPushButton("&stream");
    bstopstream = new QPushButton("STOP stream");
    bcapture = new QPushButton("capture a frame");
    Allbox = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    Allbox->addWidget(bstream);
    Allbox->addWidget(bcapture);
    Allbox->addWidget(bstopstream);

    connect(bstream,SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(startingstream()));
    connect(bcapture,SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(captureAFrame()));
    connect(bstopstream,SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(stopstreaming()));

    setLayout(Allbox);

} 

void MainThread::stopstreaming(){
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    stream.terminate();
    stream.wait();
    stream.~Streaming();
}

void MainThread::startingstream(){

    if(stream.isRunning()) return;
    stream.start();

}
```

Comment: For a similar program I just recreated the thread to restart it. In my case what you have as stream was a smart pointer.

Comment: Also terminate is discouraged in the documentation because it can cause memory leaks and other bad behaviour like a partial update of a variable...

Comment: I don't see what your meaning sorry

Comment: Instead of terminating the thread I signal it to quit. To restart the thread from the GUI thread I create a new thread object and start that.

Comment: @Engine: Was my post of _any_ help?

Answer (score 2):

```
stream.~Streaming();
```

This calls the destructor of your `stream` object. You should not call it manually, formally the object is dead after that and it may behave "interesting" after that.

For example, assume an object like this:

```
void stream::play() {
    buff_->start();
}

void stream::~stream() {
    delete buff_;
}
```

then the line `buff_->start()` might do funky things, essentially yielding undefined behaviour.

Or if it is written like this (though you should never need to manually set something to zero in a destructor; as said, the object is **supposed** to be dead after destruction):

```
void stream::play() {
    if (buff_) buff_->start();
}

void stream::~stream() {
    delete buff_;
    buff_ = 0;
}
```

then it might do plain nothing.

Comment: the problem is that I have to use this in QThread so i have to implement the streaming in run() methode, and I don't understand what you mean with buff_.